# Need help choosing a parent class for draggable objects in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm working on designing an iOS app to help users design presentations based on a few different rhetorical patterns. I'd like to build each template so that it is a container with a set of card-like objects with various attributes (different icons, borders, starter texts). The user would then be able to add/rearrange different types of those cards and edit them to design their presentation.

As I build the classes for the cards, I need them to be draggable within each presentation, and need them to be able to hold text that can be edited by the user. Can someone help point me in the direction of a class I should use as the parent for this card class? I've seen a lot of examples using UIView.  Is that the best place to start? (I'm new to both Objective C and Xcode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` is the class you're looking for. It will allow you to inset subviews for text and other attributes as well as adjust its frame and position on command.

As far as the actual dragging you can use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to keep things easy. I have an [example Github](http://github.com/emperiorEric/UIGestures) available that shows how to do basic drag and drop both for single and multiple views. It also shows some other gestures that may be of use.